# When the government starts to print money, buy a house to double or triple your money?

Tags: investing, real-estate, retirement, inflation, hyperinflation

It seems it is so obvious, but is it true?

When the government starts to do **"quantitative easing"** or print money, then the price of a house can go from $1.2 million to $1.5 million easily, or to $1.8 million after 2, 3 years.  That's because money has shrunken in value.

And the going up in price is almost unavoidable.

So if we put 20% down, i.e., $240k to buy a $1.2 million house, and it goes up to $1.5 million within a year, we have just doubled our money from $240k to extra $300k equity (the gain).  In 2, 3 years when it goes to $1.8 million, we have now tripled our money from $240k to $840k?

And if it is cash we are holding, it shrinks in value. But now, when a beef noodle changes from $7 to $12, now your $1000 changes to $2000 or $3000. (leveraged), so now the 50% price increase in beef noodle seems like a mickey mouse to you.

That sounds so much like a no-brainer.
But is it true?

Comment: Doubled your money less property tax, transaction costs, interest and maintenance, sure.

Comment: What is the significance of your investment being a house? If your market prediction is correct, your logic should apply to almost everything else too (gold, stocks of beef noodle producers, puts on your currency, calls on hedge fonds that buy houses on credit), and can be leveraged to almost every degree with a single click in your favourite broker app.

Comment: I also think you are failing to realize that if you double your money and it is worth half as much, it isn't really a get rich scheme. Owning assets is definitely better than liquid currency during high inflation, but that asset doesn't have to be a house. A stock should do roughly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. But we are all expecting the government to one day actually do something to fix the problem and then your house will be worth $1000 again or less.

Comment: @StefanieGauss Have you ever bought a house? How long do you think it takes to do that, from Day 1 of "right I've decided I want to buy a house" to Day X of "I am now the legal owner of this house". And then how long do you think it takes to sell that house again? I think you underestimate how quickly one can move when buying / selling real-estate.

Comment: @JohnFx its free money thanks to leverage, the more leverage the better. Your principal isn't inflation adjusted so you can make a ton of money (even adjusting for inflation) by holding the property for a couple of year and then selling, assuming it grows in price quickly enough.

Answer (score 7):

Home prices peaked in 2007 and then started to decline because of the 2008 Global Financial Crisis. In 2008 the Fed began Quantitative Easing. Median home value lost about 30% of their value over the next 3 years and it took another 6-7 years to surpass the 2007 high.

That period demonstrates that it's not true that:

> When the government starts to do "quantitative easing" or print money, then the price of a house can go from $1.2 million to $1.5 million easily, or to $1.8 million after 2, 3 years. That's because money has shrunken in value.

Not even close to the truth.  Home prices climb because Quantitative Easing involves the Fed purchasing longer-term securities in order to increase the money supply.  This lowers interest rates which encourages lending, investment and home buying demand.

> And if it is cash we are holding, it shrinks in value. But now, when a beef noodle changes from $7 to $12, now your $1000 changes to $2000 or $3000. (leveraged), so now the 50% price increase in beef noodle seems like a mickey mouse to you.

This is another fantabulous exaggeration.  Beef noodles (and other consumer products) have never increased 40% during periods of  Quantitative Easing.  In the past 35 years, inflation has barely topped 5% three times.  When QE began  in 2008, we had deflation for two years - consumer prices declined.

Regarding your statement that:

> So if we put 20% down, i.e., $240k to buy a $1.2 million house, and it goes up to $1.5 million within a year, we have just doubled our money from $240k to extra $300k equity (the gain).

Apart from these fallacies, you have failed to take into account possible initial repairs, mortgage interest, taxes, insurance, maintenance, and unexpected repairs. Add utilities to that list if the house isn't rented.

Your conclusion that it's a no-brainer that "When the government starts to do "quantitative easing" or print money, then the price of a house can go from $1.2 million to $1.5 million easily, or to $1.8 million after 2, 3 years"  is factually incorrect.

Comment: You have failed to take account that when the coffee, grocery started to go up in prices, and then a couple of months or a few months later the real estate agents tell you that the price of houses is starting to go up, which can give you indicator for the timing

Comment: @Stefanie Gauss: But in the part of the real world that I happen to live in, house prices started to go up years before there was any great change in grocery prices. If everyone is worrying about how to pay for their now more expensive coffee & beef noodles, a lot of them may not be in a position to buy that house you want to sell.

Comment: That's sheer genius!  When the real estate agents tell you that the price of houses is starting to go up, you should buy all that you can eat.   It's not like real estate agents would ever mislead you, eh?

Comment: @BobBaerker there are some real estate agents that you might have known for years, or some real estate agents who happened to be your friends or siblings, who, facing money, may not betray you.  Not everybody in America is bad you know... there are at least a few percent that are good

Answer (score 3):

It depends on a lot of factors. In addition to the taxes & maintenance expenses already mentioned, you have to deal with the fact that house prices are driven by supply and demand.  Looking at this century, buying a house in say Detroit would give you far different results than buying one in San Francisco.  So can you reliably predict your local real estate market?

Adding to this, if you local currency is being seriously inflated, that's almost certainly a sign of serious economic problems.  Lots of people will be out of work, and those who are working are probably getting much less, in real terms, than before inflation.  Those depending on fixed-income investments will have seen their incomes shrink.  Even those owning stocks are likely to be worse off, because the companies will have smaller markets.  Thus in real terms, housing prices are likely to drop.

The only situation where you're likely to benefit is if you actually live in the house, and you purchased it with a fixed-rate mortgage.  As long as you remain employed, and particularly if your wages increase with inflation, your fixed monthly payment will be a smaller part of your real income.